# How to further split information that was read in from a txt file using the split method in a while loop?

Tags: java, split, filereader

Say for instance, a line in the text file is:    `Richard,RL#17`

I split the data in a while loop and I can successfully get the two separate pieces of information.

Now what do i do in order to further split field [0] - the string - so that I can have "Richard" and "RL" separate. I have to split again, this time with ",".

```
  File inputFile = new File ("Personnel.txt");
  FileReader in = new FileReader (inputFile);
  BufferedReader inFromFile = new BufferedReader (in);

  String line = inFromFile.readLine ();
  int cnt = 0;

  while (line != null)
  {
     String [] field = line.split ("#");
     int age = Integer.parseInt (field [1]);
     workers [cnt] = new Personnel (field [0], age);
     cnt++;
     line = inFromFile.readLine();
  }
  inFromFile.close();

  for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i ++)
  {
     System.out.println ();
     System.out.println (workers [i]);
  }
```

So I can successfully read the data in and display it with the use of the paired object class. Now, i would like to know I would then further split the name that has "Richard,RL#17" into two separate past. Can I use the split method again, if so, how?

I have tried building another while loop but I am unsure as to how I would refer to field [0] - the name from the text file, in this case - and split it from there. I tried doing another program but was unsuccessful. The other program is as follows:

```
     File inputFile = new File ("placeHolder.txt");
     FileReader inFile = new FileReader (inputFile);

     placeHolder[] lotsOfText = new placeHolder[10];

     int cnt = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i < lotsOfText.length; i++)
     {
        String line = inFile.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
         String[] field = line.split(",");
         field = line.split("#");
         lotsOfText[cnt] = new placeHolder(field[0],field[1],field[2],field[3]);


         cnt++;
        }   
     }  

     System.out.println(field[0] + " " + field[1] + " " + field[2] + " " + field[3]);

   }
```

Comment: Hi Richard. First off, we don't really do "urgent" on Stack Overflow; questions and answers are expected to provide useful information for years, quite possibly long after the people involved in the exchange are long gone from the site. Second, we expect askers to describe what they have tried and how the results differed from the desired behavior. Please **[edit]** your question to include such information.

Comment: Please add your code so we can (hopefully) see what you mean with `field[0]` and what "the two separate pieces" are. Currently, it's hard to guess what you already have.

Comment: I apologize, I will make the recommended edits. This is my first question on stack overflow, so I am still new to the rules and regulations.

Comment: We are all beginners some time. Take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then check out the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more in-depth on how the site works and what we expect of users. Most important is probably to remember that posts should generally be self-contained (external references for complementary information are fine, but they should not be required to understand the post), and that votes are about the post, not about you.

Comment: The question is better now, but I still feel it's missing an explanation of what you have already tried to do in order to solve your problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you want to achieve.

Adding to **Manjunath Anand**'s responce:
If you want to obtain the 3 strings, "Richard", "RL", "17" from a single line in a file and then store in into an object and print it, you can do something like this:

**EDIT:** added some exception handling and tested the code:

```
public class Testing {

class Personnel {
    String name;
    String initials;
    int age;
    Personnel(String name, String initials, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.initials = initials;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

void readData() {
    File inputFile = new File ("Personnel.txt");
    FileReader in = null;
    BufferedReader inFromFile = null;
    ArrayList<Personnel> data = null;
    try {
        in = new FileReader (inputFile);
        inFromFile = new BufferedReader (in);

        // list that will hold all personnel objects
        data = new ArrayList<Personnel>();
        String line = inFromFile.readLine ();

        while (line != null) {
            String [] field = line.split("([,#])");
            String name = field[0]; // field[0] = "Richard"
            String initials = field[1]; // field[1] = "RL"
            int age = Integer.valueOf(field[2]);// field[2] = "17";
            data.add(new Personnel (name, initials, age));
            line = inFromFile.readLine();
        }
        inFromFile.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    for(Personnel p : data) {
        System.out.println("Name:\t\t" + p.name);
        System.out.println("Initials:\t" + p.initials);
        System.out.println("Age:\t\t" + p.age);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Testing test = new Testing();
    test.readData();
}

}
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks great. Now how would I display the two? The display loop still shows: Richard,RL on the output screen.

Comment: It prints "Richard,RL" because you are doing this: 
workers [cnt] = new Personnel (field [0], age);
You are still adding field[0] into the Personnel object, instead of nameAndInitials[0] and nameAndInitials[1].

There are many other ways to achieve what you want. I used an ArrayList because if you use an array, you will have to know in advance how many items you will have. 

Try the code in my answer, see if that is what you need

Comment: can you explain the "data.add"? The compiler points out an error in that line.

Comment: TestPersonnel.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Personnel(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int)
location: class Personnel

         data.add(new Personnel (nameAndInitials[0], nameAndInitials[1], age));
         
         ^
TestPersonnel.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable data
location: class TestPersonnel

         data.add(new Personnel (nameAndInitials[0], nameAndInitials[1], age));
         ^
2 errors

Comment: Same errors are being produced, "cannot Find symbol".

Comment: Everything is working fine but it just comes down to the "data.add" line. I tried changing it to "workers [cnt] = new Personnel (name, initials, age);
but the same error is produced in the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:-

```
String str1 = "Richard,RL#17";
String[] arr = str1.split("([,#])");
```

It will give you all at one shot in an array

**EDIT:**

```
    File inputFile = new File ("Personnel.txt");
    FileReader in = new FileReader (inputFile);
    BufferedReader inFromFile = new BufferedReader (in);
    // Create a scanner object which has convenient methods to read from file reader.
    Scanner s = new Scanner(inFromFile); 
    String [] field;
    String personLine;
    // Check if there is any data in the file
    while(s.hasNextLine()) {
        // read the entire line form the scanner of the file
        personLine = s.nextLine().trim();
        field = personLine.split("([,#])"); // you can put any number of delimiters within the square braces which seperate the data for person stored in the file
        // rest of your code logic
    } // keep reading till you finish all data
```

Comment: I need to be reading the information from a text file. There will be a number of listed name that follow the same pattern of having the initials after the comma, and i will need a loop in order to satisfy the further split.

Comment: @RichardLuiz please check if the edited answer suits your needs